# Как исправить подсчёт умножения цифр в матрице?

Tags: python, tkinter

Программа выводит на экран матрицу через tkinter. В самом правом столбце считается максимальное произведение цифр в числах строк матрицы. Синей рамкой выделяется строка с минимальным произведением цифр среди чисел в правом крайнем столбце(с этим проблем нет). Проблема в самом подсчёте этого произведения, оно у меня иногда считается правильно, а иногда нет(пропускает некоторые числа, произведение которых явно больше других). И ещё есть проблема с отрицательными числами, по идее программа должна считать просто цифры, не обращая внимания на знак, но этого не происходит. Пробовал делать с `abs()`, ничего не меняется.
Код целиком:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import ttk
import re

stolbi = 0

def getting1():
    global stolbi
    stolbi = 6
    

def getting2():
    global stolbi
    stolbi = 7
    

def getting3():
    global stolbi
    stolbi = 8
    

def getting4():
    global stolbi
    stolbi = 9
    

def create_matrix(event):
    global X,Y,X2,Y2,num,ROW,C,mult1,mult2,mult,maxm,a
    global new,m,b,num_list,num_list1

    COLUMN = stolbi #столбцы
    ROW = int(stroki_listbox.get(stroki_listbox.curselection())) #строки
    Y = 0
    m = []
    num_list = []
    num_list1 = []
    print(COLUMN)
    print(ROW)
    
    Canvas.delete(ALL)
    for i in range(ROW):
        m.append([])
        Y += 40
        X = 0
        for j in range(COLUMN):
            num = random.randint(-100,100)
            m[i].append(num)
            num_list.append(num)
            X += 40
            Canvas.create_text(X,Y, text=num)
    mult1,mult2 = 0,0
    maxm = -100
    mult = 0
    X2 = 450
    Y2 = 0
    new = [[0] for i in range(ROW)]
    b = []

    #num_list1.append([abs(item) for item in num_list]) - тест
    print(num_list1)

    for i in range(ROW):
        for j in range(COLUMN):
            try:
                b = list(map(int, str(m[i][j])))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            if len(b) == 1:
                mult1 = b[0]
            if len(b) == 2:
                mult2 = b[0] * b[1]

            if mult1 > maxm:
                maxm = mult1
            elif mult2 > maxm:
                maxm = mult2

        Y2 += 40
        new[i] = maxm
        Canvas.create_text(X2, Y2, text=maxm)
        mult1,mult2 = 0,0
        maxm = -100
    minimal_line()

def minimal_line():
    global m, new
    global X,Y,X2,Y2

    X = 20
    Y = 20
    Y2 = 60
    X2 = 480
    min = 100 #т.к. диапазон от -100 до 100, то больше 99 не будет

  

    for i in range(len(new)):
            if new[i] < min:
                min = new[i]

    for i in range(len(new)):
        if new[i] == min:
            Canvas.create_rectangle(X, Y, X2, Y2, outline="blue")
        Y += 40
        Y2 += 40

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x400")
root.title("main")
root.resizable(0,0)

Canvas = Canvas(width=600, height=400)
Canvas.place(x=0,y=0)


#Создание радиокнопок
r_var = BooleanVar()
r_var.set(0)
r1 = Radiobutton(text='6', indicatoron = 0, variable=r_var, value=1, width = 15, command = getting1)
r1.place(x=570,y=250)

r2 = Radiobutton(text='7', indicatoron = 0, variable=r_var, value=2, width = 15, command = getting2)
r2.place(x=570,y=275)

r3 = Radiobutton(text='8', indicatoron = 0, variable=r_var, value=3, width = 15, command = getting3)
r3.place(x=570,y=300)

r4 = Radiobutton(text='9', indicatoron = 0, variable=r_var, value=4, width = 15, command = getting4)
r4.place(x=570,y=325)


t1 = Label(text = 'Выберите кол-во строк:', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
t1.place(x=570,y=50)
t2 = Label(text = 'Выберите кол-во столбцов:', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
t2.place(x=570,y=220)



#Создание ListBox
stroki = [6,7,8,9]
stroki_listbox = Listbox(width = 10, height = 4, font = 'TimesNewRoman 14', highlightcolor = 'blue')
for number in stroki:
    stroki_listbox.insert(END, number)

stroki_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>')
stroki_listbox.place(x=570,y=100)

root.bind('<Double-Button-1>', create_matrix)

root.mainloop()
```

Часть кода в котором проблема:

```
def create_matrix(event):
    global X,Y,X2,Y2,num,ROW,C,mult1,mult2,mult,maxm,a
    global new,m,b,num_list,num_list1

    COLUMN = stolbi #столбцы
    ROW = int(stroki_listbox.get(stroki_listbox.curselection())) #строки
    Y = 0
    m = []
    num_list = []
    num_list1 = []
    print(COLUMN)
    print(ROW)
    
    Canvas.delete(ALL)
    for i in range(ROW):
        m.append([])
        Y += 40
        X = 0
        for j in range(COLUMN):
            num = random.randint(-100,100)
            m[i].append(num)
            num_list.append(num)
            X += 40
            Canvas.create_text(X,Y, text=num)
    mult1,mult2 = 0,0
    maxm = -100
    mult = 0
    X2 = 450
    Y2 = 0
    new = [[0] for i in range(ROW)]
    b = []

    #num_list1.append([abs(item) for item in num_list]) - тест
    print(num_list1)

    for i in range(ROW):
        for j in range(COLUMN):
            try:
                b = list(map(int, str(m[i][j])))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            if len(b) == 1:
                mult1 = b[0]
            if len(b) == 2:
                mult2 = b[0] * b[1]

            if mult1 > maxm:
                maxm = mult1
            elif mult2 > maxm:
                maxm = mult2

        Y2 += 40
        new[i] = maxm
        Canvas.create_text(X2, Y2, text=maxm)
        mult1,mult2 = 0,0
        maxm = -100
    minimal_line()
```

Comment: ну так и поместили бы тут минимальный воспроизводимый код, согласно правилам:-) Всем проще было бы. 148 строк некомментированной радости сейчас в данном виде.

Comment: Внёс небольшие правки, код в котором проблема чуть ниже.

Comment: Отлично. Теперь строк 57 - почти в 3 раза меньше. Только ещё тестовые примеры хорошо бы, да вывод какой-то добавить или хоть указать, где это произведение, что подаёте на вход, что ждете на выходе, а что получаете? Аналогично для отрицательных чисел. Так как у меня запуск дал просто "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: понятно, почему code 0. В коде внизу вообще ничего не запускается.

Comment: Допустим матрица будет 6x6 и её первая строка выглядит так: 87 13 -27 14 25 27. Значит справа от этой строки должно быть максимальное произведение цифр выбранное среди всех чисел в данной строке, это будет 56. И так для каждой строки. Числа могут быть в пределах от -100 до +100.

Comment: У нас явно разное представление о том, что такое "воспроизводимый пример".  Я не могу запустить ваш некомментированный код с проблемой, не вижу, куда подать эти 6 цифр, и не вижу вывода этого произведения.

Comment: Вы не сможете запустить отдельно этот кусок, т.к. вывод матрицы отображается на канвасе, который выводится не в этой функции. Запустите код целиком. Матрица заполняется рандомными числами, вам нужно просто выбрать размеры и два раза кликнуть ЛКМ по холсту.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136847/discussion-between--and-profirtos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итого, вот исправленный в ходе диалога в чате переработанный минимально воспроизводимый код части с ошибками:

```
import random

m = []
for i in range(6):
    m.append([])
    for j in range(6):
        num = random.randint(-100, 100)
        m[i].append(num)
new = []
b = []

for i in range(6):
    temp = []
    for j in range(6):
        b = list(map(int, str(abs(m[i][j]))))
        temp.append (b[0] if len(b) == 1 else b[0] * b[1])
    new.append(max(temp))
```